# Storing a mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I am new to coding, so please excuse if this is a dumb question. I have a database table

```
primary_key | main | heading | subheading | subsubheading
```

and have to return the primary key.

I have a webpage, where users go through each heading as a separate page.

I thought I could query the database based on where the user is, but then I realized I would lose what I was querying (ex. the heading) when the user went to a new page.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: post your code what you have tried ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

(your normal data getting query)

and then for page navigation

```
location.href='newpage.html?primarykey=<?php echo $row[primary_key]?>';"
```

and then on the new page....

```
<?php 
$primarykey= $_GET["primary_key"]; 
?>
```

which will grab it from the url

Comment: My current code is `<p><a href="/folder/file1.html">file1</a></p>`. If I were to enclose the whole thing in PHP block, how will my code change (as I need to store multiple variables)?

Comment: So To put the whole thing in PHP, it would look something like this...<?php echo '<p><a href="/folder/file1.html?var1=variable&var2=variable">file1</a></p>'; ?> ..... so after the link put a '?' and start putting variables following that ... and put '&' to separate each one... with php  always remember the ';' at the end of the line otherwise it wont work

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to keep your state between navigations, there are a number of approaches. One could be to set a session (the server keeps track of the state), another could be to use query-strings in the url (the url keeps track of state), and a last one would be to use the browsers localStorage (users browser keeps track).

Depending on your knowledge and requirements all could be used to solve this.

Sessions work like this, and keeps that variable until the user closes the tab or you destroy the session:

```
<?php
   // Starting session
   session_start();

   // Storing session data
   $_SESSION["whateverVariableName"] = 12;
?>
```

For the JS approach with localStorage you would just keep track of the *current* state, and not an entire database. Localstorage could store whatever is the current article index, or scroll position or whatever, write it to localStorage, and whenever the user returns it would be requested again from the server

Comment: The databases is quite large (a couple million entries), so I thought local storage wouldn't work. Would I be able to delete from local storage? Adding on to that, could you direct me somewhere that talks about the session/query-strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the "primary key" on url and can grab that by '_GET' request or you can create session to hold the params so you access it from any where. BTW also you can cache all of your data and store in it so any time you can access any data you want.

Comment: How would I pass something on url?